# No such module 'Stripe'

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm new on iOS/Cordova, and facing error with Stripe.
I imported Stripe.framework but Xcode says Stripe not found.

[image: no such module stripe]

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create bridging file for use objective C code in swift.

create a bridging header by following these procedures:

1. Add a new header file to the Donate directory by right-clicking the project directory in the project navigator, followed by clicking “New File…”.
2. Select iOS -> Source category, choose the “Header File” template and click Next.
3. Name the class “Project_name-Bridging-Header.h”, then press continue to proceed and save the file.
4. Next, go to “Build Settings”, and search for “Objective-C Bridging Header”. Set the value to “Project_name/Project_name-Bridging-Header.h”.// or simply drag file

Once done, open the Project_name-Bridging-Header.h file and write the following code:

```
#import <Stripe/Stripe.h>
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried this solution. Bridging header was already exists so i add the code to it.Then Xcode says "'Stripe/Stripe.h' file not found". it seems Stripe did not propery imported to the project.

Comment: It is restricted to use cocoapods in my environment so i didn't tried but it works now. i don't know why but using Xcode 8.2.1 solved this...(i used 8.3.1 before).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using xcode 8.3 and above. Try cleaning your project and building once you have installed the pod file.

1. Select Product > Clean. (Then wait for it to finish)
2. Select Product > Build

It solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

For people who jump in ios development with an existing project. Probably running `pod install` would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just clean your project sometimes the errors won't go away. You will need to build your project Command+B.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue while updating [stripe library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/releases) to 22.8.4 and I was in a situation that I couldn't delete all pods and install,

My team suggested to delete all the folder related to Stripe and do pod install and it worked. Hope this will help someone.